# SQLSRV in CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, dll

I have been searching for solutions and I haven't accomplished it yet, Also tried something about this, but still gives me

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:/etc.."

This are the things I have done so far :

- Downloaded the SQLSRV30.EXE
- Copy the file php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll & php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
  (Why? because the readme file says that if you have php 5.4 version then you have to copy that file to xampp/php/ext, Note that I have PHP 5.5 version but where can I download that? So i have preferred the 5.4)
- Then, i added this "extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll" & "extension= php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll" to my php.ini extensions.

We have this massive records in MS SQL 2005 so I need to work this out, Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your PHP didn't recognize the sqlsrv functions.

Check that your sqlsrv extension works in your PHP informations page. phpinfo();

If you use WAMP, it's possible that you have installed extensions in the wrong PHP directory.